# Member specialization does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

The code below compiles except for the lines

```
template <> std::map<std::string, std::function<Goo*(Foo*)>>& Factory::getMap<Goo, Foo*>() {
    return gooMap;
}
```

What is wrong here, and how would it be fixed?  The compiler (GCC 11.2) states that the member specialization does not match any template declaration, but to me it looks like it does.

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

struct Foo;  struct Goo;

struct Factory {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<Foo*()>> fooMap;
    std::map<std::string, std::function<Goo*(Foo*)>> gooMap;
    
    template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
    std::function<T*(Args&&...)> create() {
        return [](Args&&... args) -> T* { return new U(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
    }
    
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    std::map<std::string, std::function<T*(Args&&...)>>& getMap();
    
    template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
    void registerFunction (const std::string& name) {
        getMap<T, Args...>()[name] = create<T, U, Args...>();
    }
};
template <> std::map<std::string, std::function<Foo*()>>& Factory::getMap<Foo>() {
    return fooMap;
}
template <> std::map<std::string, std::function<Goo*(Foo*)>>& Factory::getMap<Goo, Foo*>() {
    return gooMap;
}

int main() {}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, where you're missing the `&` indicating that `getMap<Goo, Foo*>` still returns by reference.

Comment: All three lines.  I tried adding & and &&, and removing the && and still no go.

Comment: @ Nathan Pierson  I tried that too (changing to `Factory::getMap<Goo*, Foo*>()`).  Still no go.  Is the specialization even legal?

Comment: Trying with [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/WP4WKsY1v) at least gives a more informative error: It looks like it's complaining that it expects a `std::function<Goo*(Foo*&&)>` instead of a `std::function<Goo*(Foo*)>`. Not sure what to actually do here though.

Comment: I think what you actually wan to do is drop the `&&` from the `Args&&...` in the initial declaration of `getMap`, and possibly the return type of `create`. But I don't know the ins and outs of `function` and perfect forwarding to be doing more than trial and error here.

Comment: @ Nathan Pierson   I tried removing `&&`, i.e. using just `std::function<T*(Args...)>` and forgetting perfect forwarding altogether to simplify matters.  It will won't compile.

Comment: It compiles [for me](https://godbolt.org/z/Y3dz48e58), but then there may be calling code using `create` that's failing to compile for you that I haven't tried.

Comment: @ Nathan Pierson  So using `std::function<T*(Args...)>` (at the price of no perfect forwarding) works with clang, but not with GCC 11.2, i.e. this should be a bug report?  Still, why can't we implement perfect forwarding here?  This is only c++11 language we're using.

Comment: No, it works with [GCC 11.2](https://godbolt.org/z/61893Gn7M) as well.

Comment: @ Nathan Pierson   Thanks for everything.  I guess `std::function<T(Args&&...)>` is illegal syntax.  You should post your answer, and I'll accept it.